# jquery bootstrap modal не отображаются картинки в svg при подгрузке

Tags: jquery, json, svg, bootstrap4, modal

Есть два модальных окна на bootstrap 4 для разных целей. В них подгружается код с svg из разных источников. В источниках выдается такого рода код :

```
...
echo json_encode([
        'title'=>$th1->MainNode->title,
        'html'=>$html
    ]);
```

Код кнопок такого рода :

```
function edit_thanka(tid)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url:'ajax/thanka/edit.php?id='+tid+"&t="+Math.random(),
                processData: false, 
                contentType: false, 
                success: function(res) {
                    $('#edit_th_body').html(res.html);
                    $('#edit_th_header').html("Редактирование тханки "+res.title);
                    $('#edit_th_body .th_item').on('click', clicknode_ev);
                    $('#modalEditThanka').modal('show');
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    //$('#resdiv').html(returnval);
                    console.log('error; ' + eval(error));
                } 
            });
        /*    $('#edit_th_body').load('ajax/thanka/edit.php?id='+tid, function(responseText,textStatus, xhr) {
                $('#edit_th_body .th_item').on('click', clicknode_ev);
                $('#modalEditThanka').modal('show');
            });*/
        }
```

для каждого модального окна разный. Вроде работает. Но в какой-то момент перестают во всплывающем окне редактирования отображаться картинки внутри svg частично или полностью.

Удалось смоделировать сей глюк в вакууме :

```html
<html>
  <head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>
         <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
          Modal1
        </button>
         <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal2">
          Modal2
        </button>

        <!-- Modal 1 -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal 1</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                

<svg>
  <pattern id="pattern" width="100%" height="100%">
    <image xlink:href="https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/10/yoksel.4e/0_398a6_1f246823_M" width="300" height="200" />
  </pattern>
  <polygon fill="url(#pattern)" stroke="turquoise" stroke-width="4" points="85,0 170,61 137,161 32,161 0,61" transform="translate(65,20)" />
</svg>


              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal 2 -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal 2</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                

<svg>
  <pattern id="pattern" width="100%" height="100%">
    <image xlink:href="https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/10/yoksel.4e/0_398a6_1f246823_M" width="300" height="200" />
  </pattern>
  <polygon fill="url(#pattern)" stroke="turquoise" stroke-width="4" points="85,0 170,61 137,161 32,161 0,61" transform="translate(65,20)" />
</svg>


              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Выяснилось, что система этих паттернов и их айдишников сплошная по всей странице и нужно в таком случае делать разные айдишники для разных свгшек.